# How do I implement data binding in a View Controller in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

I have a UIKit `ViewController` that's nested inside a SwiftUI view using `ViewControllerRepresentable`. The SwiftUI view manages a bit of state (an `Int`, in this example) that I want to display in the UIKit view. When the user taps a button in the SwiftUI parent view, the state change should be reflected in the UIKit view. I've tried using the `@Binding` property wrapper to keep the two in sync, but clearly I'm missing something, as my view controller's initialiser throws a compile-time error.

I'm quite new to iOS development so perhaps I'm going in the complete wrong direction here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The code is as follows (simplified):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var currentNumber: Int

    init(currentNumber: Int) {
        self.currentNumber = currentNumber
    }

    var body: some View {
        FancyLabelViewControllerRepresentable(currentNumber: self.$currentNumber)
        Button("Increment") {
            self.currentNumber += 1
        }
    }
}

struct FancyLabelViewControllerRepresentable: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewControllerType = FancyLabelViewController

    @Binding var currentNumber: Int

    init(currentNumber: Binding<Int>) {
        self._currentNumber = currentNumber
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> FancyLabelViewController {
        let fancyLabel = FancyLabelViewController(number: self.currentNumber)
        fancyLabel.currentNumberInLabel = self.currentNumber
        return fancyLabel
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: FancyLabelViewController, context: Context) {
        uiViewController.currentNumberInLabel = self.currentNumber
    }

}

class FancyLabelViewController: UIViewController {
    var label = UILabel()
    @Binding var currentNumberInLabel: Int

    init(number: Int) {
        // Error: 'self' used in property access 'currentNumberInLabel' before 'super.init' call
        self.currentNumberInLabel = number
        // Error: Property 'self.currentNumberInLabel' not initialized at super.init call
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("Not implemented")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        label.text = "\(currentNumberInLabel)"
        view = label
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't need the

```
@Binding var currentNumberInLabel: Int
```

because the `UIViewControllerRepresentable` already takes care of updating the `currentNumberInLabel` value, but you also needs to update the

```
label.text = "\(currentNumberInLabel)"
```

So I did something like

```
class FancyLabelViewController: UIViewController {
    var label = UILabel()
    var currentNumberInLabel: Int

    init(number: Int) {
        self.currentNumberInLabel = number
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("Not implemented")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        label.text = "\(currentNumberInLabel)"
        view = label
    }
  
    func updateLabel() {
      label.text = "\(currentNumberInLabel)"
    }
}
```

and call `updateLabel` from `UIViewControllerRepresentable` as

```
func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: FancyLabelViewController, context: Context) {
    uiViewController.currentNumberInLabel = self.currentNumber
    uiViewController.updateLabel()
}
```